two wireguard interfaces with identical port (51820) but different ip ranges on same server
I am trying to set up two (or more) wireguard interfaces on a server with the same port, but different (non-overlapping) ip ranges.
The reason for the identical port is due to the connection being forwarded to port 51820 on the wireguard server, and we want to avoid changing details outside of the wireguard server.
My idea would be to change local address port from the current 0.0.0.0:51820 to e.g. 10.0.0.0/24:51820 for wg0, and 10.0.1.0/24:51820 for wg1. Is that possible or am I barking up the wrong tree with that solution?
ip address show wg0 gives me the correct ip address:(10.0.0.1/24, and 10.0.1.1/24 for wg1), but ss -tuln shows the local address port being 0.0.0.0:51820.
I would also like to drop all messages outside of the ip ranges corresponding to wg0 and wg1 on port 51820.
The server runs on ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
Clarification:
The issue is that I cannot add a 2nd interface that has the same listenport, but different ip range.
Example:
wgX.conf is:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = unique-key-for-each-X
ListenPort = 51820
Commands:
ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
ip address add dev wg0 10.40.0.1/24
wg setconf wg0.conf
ip link set up dev wg0
this works fine, but when I add the 2nd interface on a different range, but identical listenPort:
ip link add dev wg1 type wireguard
ip address add dev wg1 10.40.1.1/24
wg setconf wg1.conf
ip link set up dev wg1
returns the error "Failed to set up interface wg1: RTNETLINK answers: Address already in use"
ip address show wg0 returns
wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/none 
inet 10.40.0.1/24

ss -tuln returns 
udp  ... 0.0.0.0:51820 ... 


You should set the IPs of interfaces, not network 10.0.0.0/24. Usually 0.0.0.0 mean all IPs/interfaces

@RomeoNinov I think he meant to bind the tunnel endpoint to some address. It's not about tunneled addresses, but about the address that encapsulated packets should carry in the header.

@NikitaKipriyanov, IMHO OP try to bind two instances to two interfaces (with different networks).

To two different addresses, strictly speaking. It's not necessarily two interfaces.

Updated with an example, I hope that makes it a bit more clearer what I am trying to achieve, and if I am on the right (or wrong) track.

yes, @RomeoNinov is correct. I am trying to set up two interfaces.

@NikitaKipriyanov, also correct. In the updated example each interface has only one ip address.

It's impossible. See  this perfect answer with Linux kernel 6.0.11 WireGuard code snippets that show it doesn't support binding to certain IP. It's hardcoded to use INADDR_ANY during socket creation.

You cannot have two wireguard interfaces listening on the same port.
You can have two different wireguard interfaces listening on different ports, and then use netfilter rules to redirect traffic to achieve your goal.
For example:
On server node0, we have two wireguard interfaces; wg0 listening on port 50010 and wg1 listening on port  50011`:
interface: wg0
  public key: kItlicrv7nquOmPGP6oMNJkl0wwPbOqSBUBpgagJ9EQ=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 50010

interface: wg1
  public key: IydnbKb7fh+kCRdubNY55YOnvIs9Xfo2WJtAARsaYQs=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 50011

wg0 is using the network range 10.0.10.0/24:
3: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.0.10.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And wg1 is using 10.0.11.0/24:
4: wg1: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.0.11.1/24 scope global wg1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

In order to achieve your goal of using the same port with different listening ips, we assign multiple addresses to the server:
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c7:ae:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
    inet 192.168.124.102/24 brd 192.168.124.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 2149sec preferred_lft 2149sec
    inet 192.168.124.210/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.124.211/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec7:aee3/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And then add a couple of NAT rules. Clients connecting to 192.168.124.210:51820 will be connecting to wg0, and clients connecting to 192.168.124.211:51820 will be connecting to wg1:
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.124.210/32 \
  -p udp --dport 51820 \
  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 50010
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.124.211/32 \
  -p udp --dport 51820 \
  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 50011


On a client connecting to wg0 (10.0.10.0/24), we use the following configuration:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = kItlicrv7nquOmPGP6oMNJkl0wwPbOqSBUBpgagJ9EQ=
AllowedIps = 10.0.10.0/24
Endpoint = 192.168.124.210:51820

On a client connecting to wg1 (10.0.11.0/24), we use:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = IydnbKb7fh+kCRdubNY55YOnvIs9Xfo2WJtAARsaYQs=
AllowedIps = 10.0.11.0/24
Endpoint = 192.168.124.211:51820

And that's pretty much it: you have two wireguard interfaces associated with different network ranges. Clients connect to the same port (51820) on the server, but use different target addresses depending on which network they want.

Thank you! This is very much what I am looking for!
I will try this solution as soon as I get the chance.

You cannot reuse the same ListenPort regardless of address range, because the inner (encapsulated) IP address only becomes known after the outer UDP packet has been received and decrypted – and decryption requires that the outer packet could be mapped to a WG peer first (due to each peer association having a unique key), and that requires already knowing the WG interface.
(Additionally, it is completely valid for a tunnel interface to send and receive packets for networks beyond its own subnet, so even if the inner IP address was known, it would still be incorrect to select the incoming interface based on that information.)

Thank you for the clarification, now it makes sense why I cannot directly filter on address range.
